# How to add a totally new language in Ubuntu?

Tags: language-support

I'd like to add a totally new language into ubuntu (a native language, called shipibo conibo), but i don't know what can i do. Can you support me please? I have all the documentation (symbols, gramatic features, sintaxis features, dictionaries, etc.) and i just want to add that documentation in my computer.

Thank you very much

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations that tells you how translations work and how to get started as a translator.

Comment: I just wrote [this bug comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-translations/+bug/1882234/comments/2), which might give you a hint on what's involved. At the same time it would be good if you could define "language". Are you talking about translation, i.e. having Ubuntu displayed in your language, or typing? The latter is quite a different beast.